# How to pass SQL results to HTML with Flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I am working on a web based form used to track the creation and repair of products. Each product contains a number of assemblies, each with their own serial number and hardware revision. I have a working form for creating the products, and want to use this same template to load the serial numbers of everything that is in a product that is already in existence, so that if an assembly gets replaced, we can track the new serial number. I am using flask and mysql.

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="frontCameraSN">Front Camera SN:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-4" name="frontCameraSN" required value = {{ camera_front_SN }}>
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="rearCameraSN">Rear Camera SN:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-4" name="rearCameraSN" required value = {{ camera_rear_SN }}>
```

the values of each of the inputs corresponds to a column in a database. When I run a query, it returns a tuple that is essentially a dictionary with the column as a key and the data as the value. How do I break this tuple down so that it is a collection of variables, with the key of each as the name?

This is what is being returned

```
{'cart_SN': '123', 'center_SN': '2983098', 'drive_SN': '098', 'steer_front_SN': '093280', 'steer_rear_SN': '8098', 'led_1_SN': '098', 'led_2_SN': '098', 'led_3_SN': '098', 'led_4_SN': '098', 'camera_front_SN': '098', 'battery_board_SN': '098', 'speaker_board_SN': '089', 'ibcs_SN': '098'}
```

And here is how I am handling the query

```
cartSN=request.form['cartSN']
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="Illnevertell",
                         password="itsasecret",
                         db="thispartisright")
sql = "SELECT * FROM cart_data.cart_info WHERE cart_SN = "+cartSN
cur = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute(sql)
results=cur.fetchall()
return redirect('/carts/build')
```

I want to pass the variables as the argument to the redirect to populate the form.

Comment: Does the converting the json object to a table in the html work for you?

Comment: I need to be able to change the values, which is why I was trying to jam them into text inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out. instead of using

fecthall()

I switched to

fetchone()

since I will only return a single row at a time. I then passed the results to the redirect using **results. Works perfectly.